# Overriding parent's class method via super / yield + variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app and I have a subclass that inherits from a superclass. I would like to overload a parent class' class method. I'm trying to use a `super` block, but can I access multiple variables in the parent and vice versa?

Example:

```
class ParentClass
  class << self

    def method_to_override
      #blah blah before yield block
      yield resource if block_given?            
    end 
  end
end

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  class << self

    def method_to_override
      super do |resource|
        #code inside block where I can use resource variable
      end
    end         
  end   
end
```

How can I pass more than just the resource variable? I tried including `yield (variable1, variable2) if block_given?` but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `yield(variable1, variable2)` without space before `(`? Because this space gives syntax error.

Comment: I hope it is only a typo... your child class is not inheriting from parentclass

Comment: Writing class methods the way you did, is not recomended.

Comment: tobago, how should I write the class methods? Fer, it's a typo, I've corrected it.